# Should I use WDM when developing a file system minifilter driver? Should I use KMDF? Or is there anything wrong with it?

Tags: filter, driver, kmdf, wdm

Should I use WDM when developing a file system minifilter driver? Should I use KMDF? Or is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I suggest you give it a try and then ask a question if the code you have tried doesn't work. Use [ask] and [mcve] as guidance to prepare such question.

Comment: no, minimilters not WDM drivers. so you not use KMDF/WDM

Comment: Rene said it correct you should try to ask to the point question. Now on your query. If you are writing new driver then it is better to go for KMDF framework is newer then WDM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a filter driver to file system then you can write your driver using WDM or in a minifilter way.
but please do not use WDM since it a legacy way (do not use it). please use minifilter way to write your FSfilter.
there are plenty of samples at github which you can download and try it. i think i best point of start may be Passthrough sample.
Hope this will help.